# type javax.sound.midi.Sequence cannot be resolved

Tags: android, midi, jfugue

I am trying to use the open-source music programming API [JFugue](http://www.jfugue.org/) in my android 3.0 application, and am getting this error tag on the line `player.play(pattern);`:

```
The type javax.sound.midi.Sequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

The quickfix is configure build path, which is not the problem. This line works fine in a java application, but not an android app. How do I work around this in Android? I have the JFugue source, and could modify it to use something else if I had to. Is there anyway to get it to work, or should I use a different API?

**Update:** I tried adding rt.jar to the build path, since it contains the javax.sound.midi.Sequence type, but it created a GC Overhead limit exceeded error. It tried to build the project, got stuck at 69%, and crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not have `javax.sound.midi.*` so unfortunately libraries like JFugue don't work.

Comment: Sorry, haven't been on in a while... I discovered that myself actually, but I'll accept this, thanks :)